# found out of script not updating - roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make it so the GUI updates every time a player collects an item to show how many items they have collected. it works very well, but it only updates when the player leaves and rejoins. Any ideas??

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local catscollected = player:WaitForChild("catsCollected")
Cats_Found_Out_Of = 0

 if catscollected:FindFirstChild("sleeping cat") then
     Cats_Found_Out_Of = Cats_Found_Out_Of + 1
 if catscollected:FindFirstChild("fire cat") then
     Cats_Found_Out_Of = Cats_Found_Out_Of + 1      
    end     
end


while true do
    script.Parent.Text = Cats_Found_Out_Of.." / 3 Found"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of not putting an `if` statement into the `while` loop.

Explanation:

- Don't use `while true do`, instead of this use `while wait(0.1) do` so it will not lag the whole game on client side
- It will run only on join and leave because you haven't put the if statement into the while loop. You can either change it to the function or put into the while loop as a code.

---

Your code should now look like this:

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local catscollected = player:WaitForChild("catsCollected")

while wait(0.1) do
    Cats_Found_Out_Of = 0
    for _, v in pairs(catscollected:GetChildren()) do
      if v.Name == "sleeping cat" or v.Name == "fire cat" then
        Cats_Found_Out_Of = Cats_Found_Out_Of + 1
      end
    end
         
    script.Parent.Text = Cats_Found_Out_Of.." / 3 Found"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't really work. The number just keeps updating and getting bigger

Comment: I have updated the code and it should work now.